# Entity Framework Core throwing timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, timeoutexception

I am using the following LINQ query using EF Core and getting the following error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
> the operation or the server is not responding.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

`ECUserId` is a `varchar` column and there is no index set on this table for this column.
Also checked the collation and it is set to 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' which is case sensitive.

```
string ECUserId = "TN504060"
var userStandby = await _context.UserStandby
                                .Where(standBy => ECUserId.Equals(standBy.ECUserId, 
                                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The `userStandby` table has got around 126580 records.

Can anyone help me fix the above timeout error?

Created an index on this column but still getting the same timeout error:

```
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserStandby_ECUserId]
    ON [dbo].[UserStandby]([ECUserId] ASC);
```

The LINQ query is not generating the SQL query with the `where` condition. What am I doing wrong here please?

Thanks.

Comment: Analyze SQL and execution plan. Maybe SQL is ineffective or table has no index on `ECUserId`

Comment: Why are you comparing two *ID*s by upper casing them? The generated SQL won't be able to use any indexes. If you have a large table the server will have to check every single row. To fix this  remove `ECUserId.Equals` and use `standBy.ECUserId = thatID`. Make sure the column's collation is case insensitive *or* ensure the strings are always  converted to uppercase when saved.

Comment: Is `ECUserId` the key of `UserStandby`? In that case you could use `.Find(thatId)` and load the object directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have updated my question. please have a look. ECUserId is not the primary key. it is one of the column in that table and there is no index set so far

Comment: Add an index then. Otherwise your query will have to read and check all 100K rows. That's disk IO for 100K rows and CPU to compare 100K rows. *And* a lock on the entire table

Comment: A full table scan will have to lock the entire table for reading. To do that it will have to wait for all update (exclusive) locks to be released

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks. so adding an index will solve my issue? is that right. I am new to indexing :). what kind of index i need to add? Thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the above query in query plan not showing the where condition. not sure why?

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using? EF Core 3 and later would throw an exception if the couldn't convert an expression to SQL. Older (unsupported) ones would load the results in memory and *then* apply the expressions. Your code may be loading the entire table into memory so it can compare the string field with the argument

Comment: You need to add an index *in the database table **and** remove `Equals`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245485/discussion-between-mukil-deepthi-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Please try given exp:
`string ECUserId = "TN504060";
var userStandby = await _context.UserStandby
.Where(standBy => standBy.ECUserId.Equals( ECUserId , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

Comment: @HirenPatel that's what caused the problem in the first place and no different than the OP's code. Changing the argument order won't remove the need to either emit `UPPER` or `COLLATE` in the query, preventing the use of indexes.

Comment: You say "the LINQ query is not generating the SQL query with the `where` condition" - what SQL is it generating?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a migration script that takes a long time, you can change the command timeout like this:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
using (var ctx = new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
    var pendingMigrations = (await ctx.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync()).ToList();

    logger.LogInformation($"DataContext EFMigrations pending: {pendingMigrations.Count} ({string.Join(", ", pendingMigrations)})");

    if (pendingMigrations.Any())
    {
        ctx.Database.SetCommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalSeconds);
        ctx.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a longer timeout when setting up your DbContext:

```
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(config =>
          config.UseSqlServer(
             "MyConnectionString",
             providerOptions =>
             {
                 providerOptions.CommandTimeout(180); <-- Timeout in seconds
             })
        );
```

Comment: That's no solution, it just covers up the problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You might be right, but sometimes these things can be caused by slow internet connections.

Comment: Database connections over the internet is a very bad idea. If you need 1 minute, much less 3, to retrieve a row  by ID, something is very wrong